# how to get the length of the given web element in protractor tests

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, string-operations

I would like to find out the length of the variable which I get from the screen. If I use

```
var driverID = element(by.id('driverID')).getAttribute('value') 
driverID.length
```

it is throwing and error as `Property 'length' does not exist on type'Promise <string>`. Can some one help me in finding the length of the string.

I would also like to know how to use **string operations** in protractor tests. In this case I want to know, **if the string first index is 'character or a number' and the second index is 'character or a number'.** I want to do this by using the length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `count()` method for the number of elements inside a Promise.

Now for your specific problem, you should do something like:

```
element(by.id('driverID')).getAttribute('value').then(function(attr) {
    var length = attr.length; // I don't really need why you need this length
    if (!isNaN(attr[0]) && !isNaN(attr[1])) {
        // 1st and 2nd characters of the string are numbers.
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. Can you please let me know how to get the substring in protractor tests?

Comment: the `attr` is already a string, we already resolved the Promise and you can use direct javascript with that attribute, check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
var driverID = element(by.id('driverID')).getAttribute('value');
driverID.then((attribute) => {
    console.log(attribute.length)
});
```

the second issue you can resolve using regex